# How can I resolve a protocol lookup if I know what class will be passed to the function?

Tags: optimization, clojure, protocols

Example:

```
(defprotocol Foo (foo [x]))
(extend-protocol Foo Long (foo [x] (inc x)))

;; This is the way that I know how to do it... is there a better way?    
(def long-foo (-> #'foo meta :protocol deref :impls (#(get % Long)) :foo))
```

I am interested in this for an optimization on a task that will make the call many times, with each call taking a very short amount of time.  I have already switched from `extend-protocol` to `extend` in order to prevent an extra function call in my specific case.

Comment: If you know what class will be passed to a function then you don't need protocols because they are for dynamic runtime dispatch and in your case you already know then disptach at compile time and can use simple functions.

Comment: Imagine a "dot-product" implemented for every pair of java primitive arrays.  You would have to define a new fn for each pair because you need to have type-hinted agets on each argument.  One alternative is to use a "myget" protocol, and there are separate design issues with that, but I wanted to see what the result would look like.  Defining each pair of functions with a macro referencing a type-hinted aget directly is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather doubt that this is your bottleneck, and if it is you're unlikely to be able to improve on it without going around the protocol mechanism entirely by just defining a plain function and having the protocol implementation delegate to it.

Protocol dispatch is cached by the Clojure runtime, and also (I think) the JIT knows enough to be able to speculatively inline it, so calling a protocol function shoudln't be substantially slower than calling an ordinary function (which also does a polymorphic dispatch through the clojure.lang.IFn interface).